# MVC Razor Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm having an issue that I find very unusual, I have a view model with an entity object in it, in this case it's a meal, but if you visit the page and do not yet have a meal, it can be null, so I check it in razor, and where I check it, at the end of the null check if statement, I get the error:

> MVC Razor Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> MYAPP.Models.ViewModels.MealViewModel.CurrentMeal.get returned null.

The cursor points to the close curly brace of the if statement:

```
@if(Model.CurrentMeal != null)
{
  // html, but still throws if removed and just if exists
} // exception pointer points to this line on crash
```

CurrentMeal is indeed null in the given execution, but that's the whole point of the check.  If I remove all the html within the curly braces, it still throws the error.  If I simply output anything inside of it, it still throws.  The code works fine when there is a CurrentMeal.  I tried to add a property to the view model HasMeal and handle it in the view model to see if it was just something off in the RAZOR formatting I was missing and got the same error.  It's also very odd that it points to the close curly brace instead of the if condition itself.  In addition to this, I've removed the whole if and it works fine, and if I just render the results of the if condition it still throws when it's null, so it should just render true or false on the page, but instead throws an error.  Here's the really odd thing, The more full code looks like this:

```
<div>
  @if(Model.CurrentMeal != null)
  {
   // Render some controls to work with the meal
  }
  <div>Some controls to always have with or without a meal</div>
  @if(Model.CurrentMeal != null)
  {
   // Render some controls to work with the meal
  }
</div>
```

it throws an error on the 2nd one at the close curly brace, and not the first one.  I have been testing the pages for a couple of weeks with a valid meal, and now tested without a meal, it all works fine with a meal.  And if ONLY the if statement is removed, it works fine.

```
public class MealViewModel
{
  public Meal CurrentMeal { get; set; } // entity framework object
  // ... additional properties
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the `Model` itself is not null? What does the controller look like?

Comment: No, the model is not null, I even tried to add a property to just check if the meal was null within the view model, and it still caused the same crash.  And the error itself points to the property as being the part null, and I can hover with a breakpoint and see it's the model is valid.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the issue.  The error pointer was in the wrong place.  Nested in HTML below the end curly brace was another reference without checking null on the Meal object, once those were also wrapped in the null check the page loads as expected.  As I feared, the error was not truly in the location to which it pointed.  If you find this and are searching for a similar problem, look for other locations besides the exact location pointed to in RAZOR, my was about 10 lines down in a div tag.